# Google analytics shows Real time data but now shows data in behavior

Tags: android, google-analytics

I followed lots of post for this questions but still not solved.

**I perform google analytics for my android app and it shows Real time Screen views and events fine.
But it doesn't shows any statistics (behavior and audience data).
Since it had been implemented 72 hours ago in my app.**

Please provide me Solution for same.

Thanks in Advance.